# Slim pass attribute with request

Tags: php, slim

I am creating a simple api with [slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) .

I wanted to create a middleware to check if the token passed to the application is valid and not expired.

This is the middleware:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, $next)
{
    $token = $request->getParam('token', null);
    if (is_null($token)) {
        throw new NoTokenException();
    }

    /** @var Auth $authModule */
    $authModule = $this->getContainer()->get('AuthModule');
    $tokenModel = $authModule->validateToken($token);

    $request = $request->withAttribute('user_token_data', $tokenModel->getAttributes());

    return $next($request, $response);
}
```

It's pretty simple. I validate the token and add new attribute to the $request parameter.

In my routes I've done the following:

```
$app->post('/test', function($request, $response, $args){

    /** @var \Controller\TestController $testController */
    $testController = $this->get('TestController');

    $testController->testFunction();


})->add(new \Middleware\Test\SomeOtheroMiddleware($app->getContainer()))
  ->add(new \Middleware\AuthMiddleware($app->getContainer()));
```

In the route callback if i do `$request->getAttribute('user_token_data')` everything is in place.

But since my controller is loaded with the slim container I want to pass over the `$request` variable in the `__constructor()`

Here is my container:

```
$container['TestController'] = function ($container) {
    $testModule = $container->get('TestModule');
    $request = $container->get('request');
    return new \Controller\TestController($testModule, $container, $request);
};
```

Everything is loading, no errors, but in my `TestController->testFunction()` when I try to access the `$request` variable which I passed over with the container, I don't have the `user_token_data` key.

I can create a setter for the controller to change the `$request` in the routes, but this doesn't sound like a good idea.

I would like to know why the `$request` from the container, is not the same instance. And how can I do this without a setter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not use the request from the container. It contains stale data.

Comment: @MikaTuupola what do you suggest then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach I believe is using Slim by routing directly to the controllers.

For example:

```
class TestController {
    function routeA($request, $response) {
        $tokenData = $request->getAttribute('user_token_data');
        // Your logic here
        // in the end, return the response
        // for example: return $response->withJson(['test' => $tokenData]);
    }
}
```

And then in your route, use the following:

```
$app->post('/routeA', ['TestController', 'routeA'])->add(new \Middleware\Test\SomeOtheroMiddleware($app->getContainer()))
  ->add(new \Middleware\AuthMiddleware($app->getContainer()));
```

That will cause any `POST` request to `/routeA` to be passed directly the the `routeA` function in `TestController` and the `$request` and `$response` will be injected by Slim.

That will keep your code better organized and less coupled with the container.

As to why the `$request` is not the same in the container, that is because the container contains the original `$request` that was parsed by Slim, and once it goes through the middlewares, it is not updated in the container, because the `$request` object is immutable, so it is just passed from one middleware to the other and to your route, so the container is not aware of any changes.